# Get data from multiple html select element

Tags: javascript, dom, html-select

I'm using a MVC pattern implemented using IIFE. I get multiple conditional select boxes from the html and put them in the data model.

When I get a select(s) Node/Element contains also the options.

```
document.querySelectorAll(DOMStrings.selectDepthLevel)
```

Are options separate child Nodes or just and array inside the Select Node, meaning:

If I have a reference in my data model to the option can I get/modify attributes of the option without needing to go thru the parent Select Node ?

Comment: Options are separate elements indeed.

Comment: To answer your question: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little help :-)

```js
var select = document.getElementById("select");

var data = [{
  value: "option1",
  label: "Option 1"
}, {
  value: "option2",
  label: "Option 2"
}, {
  value: "option3",
  label: "Option 3"
}];

data.forEach(function (x, i) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", data[i].value);
  option.innerHTML = data[i].label;
  select.appendChild(option);
});

function revealData () {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data, 0, 2));
}

function revealHtml () {
  alert(select.innerHTML.replace(/></g, ">\n<"));
}

function editOption (n) {
  var option, value, label, i;
  value = prompt("Value for option #" + n + ":");
  if (value !== null) {
    label = prompt("Label for option #" + n + ":");
    if (label !== null) {
      i = n - 1;
      data[i].value = value;
      data[i].label = label;
      option = select.childNodes[i];
      option.setAttribute("value", data[i].value);
      option.innerHTML = data[i].label;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select"></select>
<button type="button" onclick="editOption(1)">Edit 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="editOption(2)">Edit 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="editOption(3)">Edit 3</button>
<button type="button" onclick="revealData()">Reveal data</button>
<button type="button" onclick="revealHtml()">Reveal HTML</button>
```